# unable to sum the values that are fetched from the database and display

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am making a project on proposal management system and I am stuck on the pricing module. Here is my **[HTML DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YRb7A/1/)**. *I have shown only required field in the output. INSERT queries below are correct.*

I am trying to AUTOMATICALLY display the sum of the *'amount'* in the *'total'* each time the user presses *'save'* button . The value of *'total'* should increment when user presses '*save*' either from *'add services'* table or from *'add products'* table. I am unsuccessful so far. HOW CAN I DO IT?

I have tried this: (Any other solution will be appreciated).

```
<td> <input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="15" id="amount" readonly="true" value=" <?php 
if(isset($_POST['save'])|| isset($_POST['psave']))
{
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db")or die("cannot connect");
    $sql = "SELECT proposal_services.service_amount AMOUNT,proposal_products.product_amount AMOUNT1, FROM proposal_services INNER JOIN proposal_products ON  proposal_products.proposal_id=proposal_services.proposal_id";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    foreach ( $row as $records ) 
    {
        $sum = str_replace(",", "", $records['AMOUNT']) + str_replace(",", "", $records['AMOUNT1']);
    }

     echo number_format( $sum, 2 );
}


?> "/></td>
```

my php code where I insert and display results is:

insert_services.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $prop_id = $_SESSION['propl_id'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['sign_user_id'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

            $name = $_POST['ser_name'];
            $desc = $_POST['txt'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $per = $_POST['per'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO proposal_services(proposal_id,user_id,service_name,service_description,service_price,per,service_quantity,service_amount) VALUES('$prop_id','$user_id','$name','$desc','$price','$per','$quantity','$amount')"))

    $sql= "select * FROM proposal_services WHERE proposal_id='$prop_id' ";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th align='center'>Service Name</th>
        <th align='center'>Description</th>
        <th align='center'>Price</th>
        <th align='center'>per</th>
        <th align='center'>Quantity</th>
        <th align='center'>Amount</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<div id='change'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['service_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['service_description']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['service_price']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['per']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['service_quantity']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['service_amount']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</table>";





?>
```

insert_products.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $prop_id = $_SESSION['propl_id'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['sign_user_id'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

            $name = $_POST['pro_name'];
            $desc = $_POST['txt'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $per = $_POST['per'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO proposal_products(proposal_id,user_id,product_name,product_description,product_price,per,product_quantity,product_amount) VALUES('$prop_id','$user_id','$name','$desc','$price','$per','$quantity','$amount')"))


    $sql= "select * FROM proposal_products WHERE proposal_id='$prop_id'";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>per</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product_description'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product_price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['per'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product_quantity'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product_amount'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type='button' value= 'edit'>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working, is the entries added from `Add Services` & `Add Products` getting added in DB properly ?

Comment: Btw, how are you ensuring that `proposal_products.proposal_id` & `proposal_services.proposal_id` is same  ?

Comment: All the values are getting inserted properly in the database. N yess, proposal_products.proposal_id & proposal_services.proposal_id are same.

Comment: Could you check if this is `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` returning any data ?

Comment: try to understand, those values which you are talking about are imported from one table itself as foreign key. I just dont know the way of achieving the answer to my question. Values are getting inserted correctly. If you have any other solution, then please show.

Comment: I was not referring to the code where in u insert the data, i was asking abt the code where ur making a join and trying to extract the values from both the tables.

Comment: yea..it is showing error. But the values are still the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47405/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-user3164770)